# Why are there only a few countries in the salary calculator?

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

In the [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) there are only a few countries listed.

[image]

Why does the [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) contain so few countries?